# Spring 4 loading static resources

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I got a spring MVC application with a bunch of css and js files currently placed in the `src/main/java/resources/assets` directory.

I read through the Spring Docs and some Tutorials on how to load these files for my templates using the [ResourceHandlerRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistry.html) class. I especially thought that the code snippets from [this Tutorial](http://imwill.com/spring-mvc-4-add-static-resources-by-annotation/#.U5GZlXKs9i4) would perfectly fit my project structure.

But I get always a 404 on my resource files.

Here is the Application/Configuration class I'm currently running with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("/applicationContext.xml") // only used for jpa/hibernate
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "at.sustain.docutools.viewer.presentation")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/js/");

    }

}
```

And here a HEADer used in my HTML files (placed in resources/templates):

```
<head>
    <!-- local Stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- local Javascript files -->
    <script src="js/general.js"></script>
    <script src="js/xmlhttp.js"></script>
    <!-- local Javascript libraries -->
    <script src="js/lib/filter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.fs.zoomer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
```

The html file is loaded correctly through my controller classes but when trying to hit e.g. my `style.css` file (`http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`) I get an 404 as already mentioned.

I can't seem to find any more resources who could provide me with more information on this subject for Spring 4. Do I miss some configuration files? Or aren't the resource handler registrations fitting my structure? I'm looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You say that your stylesheets and JavaScript files are under "/assets". I'm going to assume you have directories "/assets/css" and "/assets/js". Then, given the following resource handler definition:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**")
    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets/");
}
```

You would load these resources in your HTML like so:

```
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/js/general.js"></script>
```