# In Spring MVC (Pure Annotations), handle static resources like html, css, javascript, and images

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

In Spring MVC (Pure Annotations, no web.xml), I wish to configure, such that, in addition to using controllers to handle dynamic data, my web app can show static html, javascript, css, and images.

I am using a Maven project structure, so I keep my web source in `main/webapp/`:

```
main/
 |-> webapp/
      |-> js/
           |-> something.js
      |-> images/
           |-> image.jpg
      |-> test.html
```

I currently access my dynamic resources at `http://localhost:8080/app-name/**`

I have done a lot of research, and tried a few things, but none of them seem to work. The existing examples that I have found seem to leave out crucial pieces of information. For example, they will explain some method of configuration, but then not explain what the folder structure has to be for it to work.

An acceptable answer will explain:

- What configuration steps are necessary
- What changes, if any, must be made to my directory structure (and why they are necessary)
- What the url path will be to these static resources, based on what I have provided, above

here is my existing configuration code.

WebConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {
}
```

MyWebAppInitializer.java:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
      servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
  }

  private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      context.setConfigLocation("com.example.appname.config");
      return context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have u written the code for view resolver ?

Comment: I have tried a couple different configurations for the view resolver. None of them worked, so I went back to the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

For handling static resources using pure Java Configuration, your `WebConfig` class should extend this [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) class and override [addResourceHandlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) method.

You can check these links for more information - [1](https://imwill.com/spring-mvc-4-add-static-resources-by-annotation/#.VnWjBRV97IU), [2](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080025/spring-4-loading-static-resources)

Comment: The second of those links is pretty good, and eventually, helped me figure this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your WebConfig:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
     @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you consider fleshing out your answer to include the info I requested explaining how this configuration relates to the file structure and url patterns?