# JSP doesn't load resources

Tags: spring, validation, jsp, jakarta-ee

I got a problem with loading resources. I'm using header.jsp to get the same header. There are some js and css but my own js doesn't load to it but everything else is loaded. Otherwise Bootstrap couldn't work.

My header.js which is in WEB-INF/view/fragments

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=uft-8">
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <script href="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script href="<c:url value="../resources/js/validation.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I included the header in my JSP like that `<%@include file="../fragments/header.jsp" %>`

I also have in the spring-servlet.xml this tag `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

[image: My structure of resources]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 4 loading static resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080025/spring-4-loading-static-resources)

Comment: Your local js? then try `<script href="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>` , ignores that first `/` in front of the *resource*.

Comment: why shoudl i ignore it?

Comment: I tried that. Not working. Even I can't open the source in the browser..

Comment: I changed to <spring:url value="/resources/js/validation.js" var="validation"/>
        <spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootstrap.js"/>
        <script src="${bootstrap.js}"></script>
        <script src="${validation}"></script>